# What would cause importing the pandas module to kill python without an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-import

Whenever I attempt to import `pandas`, python just dies, with no errors to show. This applies to interactive python as well as files.

I've attempted reinstalling pandas and numpy. I've attempted reinstalling Python while clearing all the files located in appdata.

What I am trying to run:

```
import pandas

print("Here we are!")
```

Fails with no error whatsoever. The print statement never runs.

Expected results would be that the script or whatever it may be runs and uses Pandas.

**Python Version**: 3.7.3 (*Windows 10*)

How I execute the script:

`python ./script.py`

I've also attempted interactive mode:

```
PS C:\scripts> python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
PS C:\scripts>
```

Both end the same, without any feedback.

Comment: huh that's weird. i'm assuming you're running this script through the command prompt?

Comment: Yeah, generally running out of VSCode, but I've also tried a separate powershell window.

Comment: how do you run it?

Comment: @zero I've updated my post with some notes on how I run it.

Comment: how are you installing your packages? through `pip`?

Comment: Yeah, just using pip with the --user param.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this  @Odinson?

Comment: @BSHuniversity Not that I recall. I've since been able to move my development to a Linux machine where this problem doesn't occur. I did pull up the VM that I ran into the issue on and it is still an issue on there.